# how to upload excel without browse option in php

Tags: php, upload

i can easily upload excel if i used simple

```
<input type="file" name ="file">
```

this function simple browse the file and using simple php code excel data is saved in the data base. I need to upload excel file in some directory on time bases by cron job . i know very well cron job but. i am unable to do without input type file there is any way to upload file with using file type.

Pl z suggest me if any solution for that i waiting.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Why would you want to involve an input element when you're dealing with a cron job? A cron job would run some software, not present a user with an HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wget or curl, see this thread on Superuser for examples:

https://superuser.com/questions/86043/linux-command-line-tool-for-uploading-files-over-http-as-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 0):

The **rename** function does this (delete old file)

```
rename('text.xls', 'folder_2/text.xls');
```

[PHP RENAME DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

if you want to keep old file

The **copy** function

```
copy('text.xls', 'folder_2/text.xls');
```

[PHP COPY DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)